# Projects or docker images isolation

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I need create some different projects in Kiwi TCMS and set different roles for Alice, Bob and Vasya:

- Alice is Tester in Project A and Project B but have not access to Project C
- Bob is Tester in Project A and have not access to Project B and Project C
- Vasya is PM in Project A, Project B and Project C. He can set permissions for Alice and Bob and can set any role for any tester in any project (but only A, B or C)

How I can do it?

If it impossible, how I can start 3 or more instances Kiwi TCMS but with only one project in it. And how I can update those instances?

Answer (score 0):

> How I can do it?

Three separate instances of application via docker - see https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing_docker.html or multi-tenant installation - see https://github.com/kiwitcms/tenants.

Answer (score 0):

> how I can start 3 or more instances Kiwi TCMS but with only one project in it.

You can start as many instances as you want because they are just separate containers. You can use the same image + DB but create multiple instances or create multiple databases on the same DB server  + multiple web servers - there are multiple possibilities and the configuration is up to you.  It all happens in docker-compose.yml.

If you are looking for a single instance which provides isolation between multiple data sets the check-out kiwitcms-tenants: https://github.com/kiwitcms/tenants. A tenant can be a single project (with multiple products) a single team or a mixture of people from multiple teams. With a multi-tenant instance accounts are kept on the public schema and access can be granted in a many-to-many fashion.

kiwitcms-tenant is an add-on which you can install & configure in your own docker images. Alternatively you may opt into the Kiwi TCMS Enterprise image which has this add-on already included.